# IntelliJ code style keep method name and parameter on the same line

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying to create a code style in IntelliJ to keep formatting consistent. At the moment, I have a problem where IntelliJ reformats a line very strangely.

```
                                                        |
someCollectionMethod().stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).map(...)
                                                        |
```

The right margin is where the `|` are. IntelliJ reformats this to

```
someCollectionMethod().stream().filter
        (Objects::nonNull).map(...)
```

I find this to be incredibly strange and would much rather it take the method name to the next line as well like

```
someCollectionMethod().stream()
        .filter(Objects::nonNull).map(...)
```

I want the margin to be enforced but not in such a strange way. I can't find any setting about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under `File > Settings` then `Code Style > Java` choose the "Wrapping and Braces" tab

I suspect you have this option checked: "Ensure right margin is not exceeded". This causes IntelliJ to chop at the 'right margin'.

Further down that list you'll find a section title "Chained method calls" and to its right, the value "Do not wrap". If you click on that value a drop down will appear, choose "Wrap if long" from that drop down and Intellij will wrap that chained method call for you thereby avoiding the more brutal 'chop at right margin' instruction.

[image]